# Why is a Python generator confusing its scope with global in an exec'd script?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-exec

Ok, so I'm working in an environment where a config script for a tool is an `exec`'d python script.  The exec call is something like this:

outer.py:

```
exec(open("inner.py").read(), globals(), {})
```

Now, I want to do some relatively basic iteration within the `exec`'d script.  In this case, doing work when some values aren't in the whitelist:

inner.py:

```
items = (
  'foo/bar',
  'foo/baz',
  'foof',
  'barf/fizz',
)

whitelist = (
  'foo/',
)

for key in items:
  try:
    # Not terribly efficient, but who cares; computers are fast.
    next(True for prefix in whitelist if key.startswith(prefix))

  # Do some work here when the item doesn't match the whitelist.
  except StopIteration:
    print("%10s isn't in the whitelist!" % key)
```

---

Running `python inner.py` yields the expected result:

```
      foof isn't in the whitelist!
 barf/fizz isn't in the whitelist!
```

**Here's the strange part:** Running `python outer.py` seems to show that the interpreter is confused about the scope of the generator:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "outer.py", line 1, in <module>
    exec(open("inner.py").read(), globals(), {})
  File "<string>", line 15, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 15, in <genexpr>
NameError: global name 'key' is not defined
```

---

Some other notes:

- You can `print(key)` just fine inside the `for` loop (before the generator is run).
- Replacing the empty dict with `locals()` in the `exec` line of `outer.py` resolves the issue, but that code is out of my control.
- I'm running the OS X built Python 2.7.2 (Mountain Lion).

Comment: Interesting also: If you run it with `locals()` instead of `{}` once, and then replace it with `{}` again, it won't print anything. Why are you doing the weird `next()` thing when you could just add another `for` loop, though?

Comment: the `next` call is to just break out once I find a value in the whitelist.  IMO the extra `for` loop is a bit more awkward due to requiring a temp `found` var.  (In my actual code I'm trying to test for items that _don't_ match)

Comment: I too am curious. It seems like a really strange bug. I just was a bit more confused about what your `next` call was doing (I think that relying on something throwing exceptions is bad form, but maybe that's just me).

Comment: Heh, yeah - it'd be nice if there was a simple `find_first` helper in `itertools` or whatever; but `next` appears to be the most straightfoward way :(

Comment: The whole `try: next( .. )` block is just a weird way to write `if any(key.startswith(prefix) for prefix in whitelist)` .. or avoiding `break` at all cost.

Comment: `any`! That's what I've been looking for all this time ><

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dodgy indeed.

From the [doc](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#exec):

> If two separate objects are given as globals and locals, the code will
>   be executed as if it were embedded in a class definition.

(Note that when you run `exec(..., globals(), locals())` at module level, this does not apply, because `globals() is locals()`, i.e. not two separate objects).

This indicates you can simply reproduce the problem by running this script:

```
class A(object):

  items = (
    'foo/bar',
    'foo/baz',
    'foof',
    'barf/fizz',
  )

  whitelist = (
    'foo/',
  )

  for key in items:
    try:
      # Not terribly efficient, but who cares; computers are fast.
      next(True for prefix in whitelist if key.startswith(prefix))
      # Found!
      print(key)
    except StopIteration:
      pass
```

"Ok, but why do I get the error here?"

So glad you asked.  The answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1773636/class-attribute-evaluation-and-generators).

Comment: I also missed it the first time reading. The human mind tends to focus on the things it thinks it knows, sometimes ignoring the things which don't make sense. Glad I could help ;)

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just add an inner for loop there:

```
for key in items:
    for prefix in whitelist:
        if key.startswith(prefix):
            print(key)
```

I'm pretty sure you won't get that error and it's much simple/easier to read.

Comment: Yeah, I agree that for my example, the nested `for` loops is far better to read!  However, in my actual use case, I'm trying to do work when things _don't_ match (and the doubly-nested `for` loop breaks down a bit with that)